# Game tree in latex of 6 levels

Tags: tikz-trees

I am using this code but would like to get 4 additional levels is that possible?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,font=\footnotesize]
% Specify spacing for each level of the tree
\tikzstyle{level 1}=[level distance=12mm,sibling distance=18mm]
\tikzstyle{level 2}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=15mm]
\tikzstyle{level 3}=[level distance=12mm,sibling distance=18mm]
\tikzstyle{level 4}=[level distance=15mm,sibling distance=15mm]
% The Tree
\node(0)[solid node,label=above:{$P1$}]{} 
child{node(1)[solid node, white]{}
}
child{[white] node(2)[solid node, yshift=-22]{}  %note that you need to adjust the yshift if you change the sibling distance
child{[black] node[hollow node,label=below:{$(a,b)$}]{} edge from parent node[left]{$C$}}
child{[black] node[hollow node,label=below:{$(c,d)$}]{} edge from parent node[right]{$D$}}
 edge from parent node[black, xshift=0,yshift=-42]{$\alpha$} %note that you need to adjust the yshift if you change the level distance
}
child{node(3)[solid node, white]{}
}
;
% information set
    \draw[solid,bend right](1)to(3);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I would like to create a game tree looking like this 
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Could you please make a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get? How are `solid node` and `hollow node` defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [istgame](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame) package, you can do like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[scale=1.5,font=\footnotesize]
\xtShowEndPoints
\cntmdistance{12mm}{30mm}
\xtdistance{12mm}{15mm}
% period 1
\cntmAistb{0}[at end,left]{1}[at end,right]
\istrootcntmA(1){Player 1}
  \istbA[draw=none]{s_1}[very near end]
  \endist
\istroot(1a)(1-1)
  \istb{Accept}[al]{(s_1,1-s_1)}
  \istb{Reject}[ar]
  \endist
% period 2
\cntmAistb{0}[at end,left]{1}[at end,right]
\istrootcntmA(2)(1a-2)<0>{Player 2}
  \istbA[draw=none]{s_2}[very near end]
  \endist
\istroot(2a)(2-1)
  \istb{Accept}[al]{(\delta s_2,\delta(1-s_2))}
  \istb{Reject}[ar]
  \endist
% period 3
\cntmAistb{0}[at end,left]{1}[at end,right]
\istrootcntmA(3)(2a-2)<0>{Player 1}
  \istbA[draw=none]{s_3}[very near end]
  \endist
\istroot(3a)(3-1)
  \istb{Accept}[al]{(\delta^2s_3,\delta^2(1-s_3))}
  \istb{Reject}[ar]
  \endist
% period 4
\cntmAistb{0}[at end,left]{1}[at end,right]
\istrootcntmA(4)(3a-2)<0>{Player 2}
  \istbA[draw=none]{s_4}[very near end]
  \endist
\istroot(4a)(4-1)
  \istb{Accept}[al]{(\delta^3s_4,\delta^3(1-s_4))}
  \istb{Reject}[ar]{\vdots}
  \endist

\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, if you are the maintainer of this `istgame` package, is it possible to specify it here: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/who-are-the-package-maintainers-here?

Comment: I added the `istgame` package to the list.